# Managing non spatial tables with geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I am developing an application involving PostGis+Geoserver+QGIS, the application is basically a QGIS plugin, as client of Geoserver. We need to manage forms related to some spatial data (more than one form per spatial item). I would like to know if there is any way using Geoserver to manage the editing of these forms stored in a non spatial table. In summary, Is Geoserver capable  of managing non spatial tables (including read and write)

Comment: So you have one to many relation between geometries and forms? It may be a bigger problem than not having geometries in tables.

Comment: Yes, this is the relation between the two tables. My concern is about how Geoserver manages non spatial tables and if it is possible to use WFS-T (or any workaround) to perform writing tasks in the database using Geoserver.

Comment: This is too special for me. One to many relations means diving into complex features and application schemas. Read http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html and think if you can model your case as an application schema. The GeoServer app schema specialists follow geoserver-users list more actively than this forum.  However, I am not sure if WFS-T works with complex features.